# custom embeds not showing up

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am making bot, that takes a command followed by a string which outputs an embed

My idea is to have it follow this guideline: al_emb "Title Here" "Description Here"

my code so far:

```
@bot.command()
async def emb(c,embed):
    #first = c.content.split()[1]
    #second = c.content.split()[2]
    first = c.content
    #embed = embed.Embed(title=first, description=second, color=0x00ff00)
    embed = embed.Embed(title=first, color=0x00ff00)
    await c.send(embed=embed)
```

I am getting no output

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: Is the bot sending blank messages?

Comment: it's not sending anything, if I however do plain "al_emb" I get commands.MissingRequiredArgument error

Comment: If it's not sending anything with the code you gave, you should check that your bot has "embed permissions" in your server

Comment: the bots have admin, so it should have all pers and channel overrides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that ctx has no attribute content. Try this function instead:

```py
@commands.command()
async def emb(self, ctx, *, args): # "self" assuming this command is in a cog
    embed = discord.Embed(title=args, color=0x00ff00)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: my code is in a cog FYI

my goal is to have this be the setup for the command: https://imgur.com/a/xdEsFyR

When I use the code you provided I am getting a "Command does not exist" error, my error handler outputs this when `commands.CommandNotFound`

I am also getting an error: `Undefined variable 'discord'`

Comment: just put `import discord` at the top of your file, or however you were doing embeds before @DanA

Comment: @DanA if you are getting `commands.CommandNotFound`, then you must have called a command that doesn't exist. That error can't be caused by the command itself.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/tqS5qcp
I am using the command `al_emb test` and getting no output

Comment: First, the functions should be unindented one level. They aren't part of `__init__`. Second, the first function uses `@bot.command`, wheras the second uses `@commands.command`. After unindenting, make sure they are both `@commands.command`.

Comment: Ding Ding Ding CORRECT ---- I only have one more question, how  do I also do description

Comment: @DanA `embed = discord.Embed(title="titile", description="description")` I think you had it right before

Comment: Thas not working, How would I separate `Title` from `description`,   i.e: al_emb "Title" "Description"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214684/discussion-between-l-d-and-dan-a).

Comment: are you getting my messges?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the two arguments in the coroutine's signature:

```
class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    @commands.command()
    async def emb(self, ctx, title, description):
        embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=description, color=0x00ff00)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: thought I would mention that I am using this command in a cog and also with that code the bot does not output anything